# The string formatting methods with "f"

Tags: python-3.x, methods, string-formatting, nameerror

**Hi, everybody.**

I tried using *string formatting* methods with *"f"*.

```
bro_name = "firstname"
bro_surname = "surname"
bro_age = "six"
bro_info = f"{firstname} {surname.upper()}, {six}."
print(bro_info)
```

But I'm new to *Python programming* and don't understand why something went wrong.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/xxx_/PycharmProjects/anaisproject/string.py", line 25, in module
>    bro_info = f"{firstname} {surname.upper()}, {six}."
>   NameError: name 'firstname' is not defined

**Thank you in advance for your advice.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstname` and `surname` are the strings that are placed in variables `bro_firstname` and `bro_surname`. You was writing non-existant variable names - prepend `bro_` to them, because you named the variables like that.